# How to reduce or eliminate flash reflections on eyeglasses in post?

Tags: software, reflection, masks, luminance

First off, I know how to do this in the studio. Not gonna happen. This is an obituary photo.

Second off, I don't do software subscriptions, so Photoshop is out. I know how to do this in Photoshop: create a luminance mask, invert it, then paint the clone or healing tool on the reflection. It will only take effect where the mask is black — where the bright white glare is — and will have progressively less effect where the mask is lighter.

So I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this with other Mac photo software besides Adobe. The ones I have seem to lack the concept of a luminance mask. I have recent versions of Luminar Neo, Affinity, ON1, Capture One, OM Workspace, and even digicam, darktable, and GraphicConverter 11 at my disposal.

Here is the image I'm working with:
[image]

If you know of the perfect tool for this, I'm even willing to spend a modest amount on such a tool, but would rather learn how to bend some software I have to the task.

Thanks in advance for your ideas!

Comment: I'm pretty sure ON1 has luminosity masks, even automatic selection for them based on brightness. I haven't used luminosity masks in my limited experience with ON1, though.

Comment: I hadn't seen them in ON1. I'll give it a look — thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do [luminosity masks on Gimp](https://patdavid.net/2013/11/getting-around-in-gimp-luminosity-masks.html). This can be a bit more "manual" but there are [scripts to help](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-ofn-luminosity-masks).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option is probably using Affinity Photo with cloning/healing brushes on a duplicate layer; and maybe a curves layer masked in.

before

[image]

after

[image]

[Video Tutorial](https://youtu.be/EGK4bsR6LwE)